# Problems installing ember-cli using npm on c9.io IDE

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, cloud9-ide

I am trying to install phantom-js on a c9.io virtual machine / cloud IDE and I get the following error:

```
$ sudo -s npm install --global ember-cli
...

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
28 info install phantomjs@1.9.16 into /nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib
29 info installOne phantomjs@1.9.16
30 info /nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs unbuild
31 info /nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs unbuild
32 error error rolling back Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs'
32 error error rolling back  phantomjs@1.9.16 { [Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs']
32 error error rolling back   errno: 56,
32 error error rolling back   code: 'EROFS',
32 error error rolling back   path: '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs' }
33 error Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs'
34 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
34 error including the npm and node versions, at:
34 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
35 error System Linux 3.14.13-c9
36 error command "/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/bin/node" "/mnt/shared/sbin/npm" "install" "-g" "phantomjs"
37 error cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace/Instagram-Scrap
38 error node -v v0.10.28
39 error npm -v 1.4.3
40 error path /nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phantomjs
41 error code EROFS
42 error errno 56
43 verbose exit [ 56, true ]
```

I cant figure out what the error is. I tried installing other packages, but even they give the same error on this machine.

---

#### Update:

The -g flag fails but local install works

Comment: `EROFS` suggests to be a problem with the filesystem, normally FileDystem it's used under the acronym FS. Did checked our permissions in node/npm binaries and permission on the node_modules/ folder?

Comment: @PauloOliveira It was working just a few hours ago, and I have not done anything to touch the workspace. Beyond that, the system is under c9.io's control. Also only global install doesnt work.

Comment: I have user Cloud9 before with Python (pip), Java (maven) and Nodejs (npm).
And I didn't get any error or problem because system restrictions.
Not sure, while writing, but I think you can do `sudo -s` to change to root user. And your environment is isolated from the other, so...

Comment: you shoul add to the question which command you executed.

eg: `sudo npm install -g phantomjs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `sudo` while installing modules globally on Cloud9. I just tried the following command:

`npm install -g ember-cli`

which completes without any problems.

```
$ which ember
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin/ember
```

Also, yeah, how come your workspace is using node v0.10.28, did you install node yourself? Your paths should be /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/ based, not /nix/... Please try this again on another workspace. There's something wrong with the configuration here

Comment: As explained in the question it is not working for me

Comment: Your question states you ran it with sudo, have you tried without it? The error cannot be the same even if it fails. What is the error without sudo?

Comment: Sorry, the question was edited. With or without, the error is the same. I'm looking to update the node version to see if that solves it.

Comment: Can you try again and email at support@c9.io if it doesn't work please. Thanks!

Comment: Also, yeah, how come your workspace is using node `v0.10.28`, did you install node yourself? Your paths should be `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/` based, not `/nix/...` Please try this again on another workspace. There's something wrong with the configuration here

Comment: Also, your errors are based on installing phantomjs, which (looking at my install) is not a dependency of ember-cli. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Yes I have installed some versions of node myself. If that helps? And changing versions solved the problem for the newly installed versions. Your comment helped me find the issue. Could you please include it in your answer so I can accept it?